# How to call intent for an activity in android?

Tags: android, push-notification

I am developing an android app . I am able to send the push notification to app through parse REST API. 
But I need to send action field ( intent ) in the REST api to open the correct screen . 
Currently its just opening the home screen .

Now its just opening the home ( main screen ) .How will I be able to specify the intent to open the brand activity class (test.mm.brand) through the parse REST API

My android manifest file is as below.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MofActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name="test.mm.brand" />
<activity android:name="test.mm.CustomizedListView" />
<activity android:name="test.mm.HallofFame" />
<activity android:name="test.mm.VideoList" />
```

REST request

```
curl  -X  POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ntItEUY1LZ949R9zfTWDuZORE6dnjICxOni9L9nU" -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: dwYZ2DeKutwtswDgWTYkboIw6hRplwSNDR20GiMt" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{ "where": { "deviceType": "android" }, "data": { "alert": "Your suitcase has been filled with tiny robots!", "action": "test.mm.brand", "title" : "dddd" } }' https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

Comment: What info are you sending through the RestAPI?

Comment: added it in the question

Comment: And how are you creating the notification ?

Comment: through the same REST API request i added

Comment: @rrmo hey if your problem solved lease provide me a demo... will be helpful..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a receiver to get the notification as given here [Parse Android Notification - responding to payloads](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications)

Add this to your manifest

```
<receiver android:name="test.mm.MyCustomReceiver">
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="test.mm.brand" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Create this class

```
public class MyCustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "MyCustomReceiver";

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
      String action = intent.getAction();
      if(action.equalsIngnoreCase("test.mm.brand") {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, test.mm.brand.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i); 
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah . But i want to do this through REST API .

Comment: You can send information through the REST API, and using this info you can decide in the default activity , where you want to redirect it to.

Comment: ok .But action field in the REST API takes an Intent. We don't need to do this in the App code. How do I trigger the intent through REST API ?

Comment: Thanks had to make a small change .

Comment: @rrmo what change did you have to make?

Comment: Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("test.mm", "test.mm.brand");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);

Comment: startActivity cannot be called as this class is not extending Activity class. Thanks for the help.

Comment: when we set the default activity in the main activity class using PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MyPushReceiver.class);
where MyPushReceiver is default activity
Now when i send the parse REST request with the same fields including action field ( test.mm.brand )
how do I access this value in the default activity class in my App
i.e in the onCreate Method

Comment: You cant access it in `onCreate` Method. When the push comes in from parse the `onReceive` will get fired. Here in you will be able to access the values.

Comment: Yeah that is the case if we use receiver in manifest . But when we use the PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(...) then an activity is fired by default . How do i get the REST fields in this function . The reason I am asking this because when we use the broadcast receiver it automatically open up the correct screen using background functionality, but when we click on the notification it opens up the default screen set in parse callback function .

Comment: You can use `getIntent()` in oncreate to get the Intent and get the action from it.

Comment: @rrmo can we open other activity then main by push?

Comment: I have tried this but didn't worked for me any idea.

Comment: I am getting all the data on my Custom broadcast receiver but How do  I process that data or how can I get that data using getIntent() and in which class so, I can use that data and start an activity using certain values?